# How to get user Activity using aweber api

Tags: php, rest, aweber

i am trying to get user activity via aweber rest api using thier [aweber php library](https://github.com/aweber/AWeber-API-PHP-Library).

**code:**

```
$all_subscribers = $account->findSubscribers($params);
    foreach ($all_subscribers as $sub) {
       echo "<p><strong>Name:</strong>  {$sub->name}</p>";
       echo "<p><strong>Email:...;
       foreach ($sub->getActivity() as $event) {
           echo "<p>{$event->type}: {$event->event_time}</p>";
        }
}
```

i am able to get the details such as event type and event timing but i also need to fetch title and the url of the message on which the events were happened.
i also tried `$event->self_link` but it was no help.

Here is the data return by `getActivity()` method

```
[data] => Array
    (
        [event_time] => 2017-04-30 07:05:00-04:00
        [resource_type_link] => https://api.aweber.com/1.0/#open
        [http_etag] => "28eb617e4d24407e49b14a9402608f423da2f4a7-ca5feee2b7fbb6febfca8af5541541ea960aaedb"
        [subscriber_link] => https://api.aweber.com/1.0/accounts/1011749/lists/4120909/subscribers/59065294
        [self_link] => https://api.aweber.com/1.0/accounts/1011749/lists/4120909/campaigns/f28501689/messages/40127/opens/15096
        [type] => open
        [id] => 15096
    )
```

[image: the links the i am trying to fetch]

Comment: We actually discovered recently that there's a bug in the API right now with the analytics for campaign messages. The response does not contain proper message information for campaigns, as you see here. It will contain the message subject and ID and all of that for broadcasts or followups, but messages in campaigns will be missing that information. Our developers are aware of the issue, but I currently do not have an estimate for when the fix will be released. We don't monitor StackOverflow for questions on a daily basis, so if there are any followup questions or reports of this bug, please re

Comment: thanks @KaitlynChappell for the response i hope you guys will fix it soon.